# div element fixed relative to window but limited to its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position a box in a fixed way relative to the window, but only within the limits of a certain section of the site. You can visualise this easier in the jsfiddle that I created.

https://jsfiddle.net/animyrch/dzrpg6gh/

My element (the yellow box) needs to remain where it is on the screen. And it does exactly that. But the wrapper element (blue box) has a height of 20em. And when the screen is scrolled further than that, the fixed element continues to stay on the screen and goes out of its wrapper. How can I ensure that it doesn't go further than a specific point (for example, after 19 em or the starting point of the padding or the border of the wrapper, etc.) and starts to disappear from the screen as the scrolling goes on?
I have searched for an answer but all my search queries are understood as "keeping an element fixed relative to its parent". It's true that when the fixed element reaches a certain point, I want it to be no longer fixed relative to the window but relative its parent but it's clear that it's not the same thing.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Here is the code from jsfiddle:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixedElement">
        <p>This should stay fixed on screen but shouldn't go lower than its parent</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="enlargingPage"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;   
  height: 20em;
}

.fixedElement {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
}

.enlargingPage {
  background-color: gray;
  height:30em;
}
```

Comment: you mean this?  - https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky/

Comment: yes, this was what I was searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is `position: sticky`. Check the MDN documentation on how to use it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Remember browsers natively don't support it much. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

You can obviously polyfill it using one of the polyfills out there. Example - https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill